# Redirect non .onion to https but keep .onion as http?

Tags: nginx, tor

I am adding a .onion address to my site and need to redirect regular traffic to https and .onion traffic to keep as http. I've got:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
  if ($host !~* "\.onion$") { # error occurs here
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in nginx.conf:22
```

Comment: You could use multiple `server` blocks instead and avoid the `if` statements.

Comment: My server block in real life is reaaaaaally long. I don't want to have to duplicate all my location blocks, headers, etc....would be error prone.

Comment: Offload common configuration into a separate file and use an `include` statement.

Comment: I think it is not possible because both http traffic and onion traffic must go through 80 port. You cannot have 2 server blocks listening to the same port.